# Como armazenar valor em uma variável e retornar seu tipo primitivo e outras informações

Tags: python, revisão-de-código

Preciso fazer um programa que leia algo pelo teclado e mostre na tela o seu tipo primitivo e todas as informações possíveis sobre ele.

Ainda estou desenvolvendo o código. Porém já percebi um erro e não sei como corrigi-lo.

Segue meu código:

```
n1 = float(input('Digite alguma coisa: '))

print('{} é', type(n1), 'além disso, ele é'.format(n1))
```

Após dar "run" no código, o local onde deveria estar o "n1", continua aparecendo "{}".

Comment: Por favor, tente formular melhor a sua dúvida. Veja esses links sobre como fazer perguntas aqui https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta?cb=1 e aqui https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-sopt-vers%c3%a3o-curta?cb=1.  Por exemplo: no título da pergunta, coloque a sua dúvida para que as pessoas já identifiquem o que você precisa. Também é preciso que marque em tag a linguagem que você está utilizando. Veja outras dúvidas e tente seguir os modelos.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você faz:

```
print('{} é', type(n1), 'além disso, ele é'.format(n1))
```

Está passando 3 argumentos para `print`, já que eles estão separados por vírgula:

- a string `'{} é'`
- o resultado de `type(n1)`
- o resultado de `'além disso, ele é'.format(n1)`

São 3 valores "independentes", ou seja, cada um deles é passado separadamente, e `print` imprime um a um.

Isso quer dizer que o [método `format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) só é aplicado à string `'além disso, ele é'`, e como não tem o *placeholder* `{}` nesta string, não há o que ser substituído.

Enfim, uma alternativa para o seu caso é colocar tudo em uma única string e chamar `format` passando os valores que você quer:

```
print('o valor da variável é {}, e seu tipo é {}'.format(n1, type(n1)))
```

Ou, se estiver usando Python >= 3.6, pode usar [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
print(f'o valor da variável é {n1}, e seu tipo é {type(n1)}')
```

Repare no "f" antes das aspas, isso indica que é uma *f-string* e que eu posso colocar os valores a serem impressos dentro dos colchetes.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar um f antes da `string` no `print` e o n1 dentro do {}, assim o python vai executar o que tiver dentro

Ex:

```
n1 = float(input('Digite alguma coisa: '))

print(f'{n1} é', type(n1), 'além disso, ele é'.format(n1))
```